# Contar el la variable $i de un ciclo flor

Tags: php

Hola buen dia tengo un ciclo for lo que necesito es contar cuantos elementos me trae el for ejemplo 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 = 7. y obtener el resultado que es 7.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])) {
  $datos = $_SESSION['carrito'];
  for ($i=0; $i < count($datos); $i++) { 

  }
}
```

es para crear la notificacion de cuantos productos hay en el carrito.
ejemplo del codigo.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
<?php 
  $total = 0;
  if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
      $datos = $_SESSION['carrito'];
      $total = 0;
      for ($i=0; $i<count($datos); $i++) { 
  ?>
    <div class="producto">
        <div class="card border-success" style="width: 13rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="admin/productos/<?php echo $datos[$i]['Imagen'];?>" width="20" height="150" alt="<?php echo $datos[$i]['nombre_producto'];?>" title="<?php echo $datos[$i]['nombre_producto'];?>">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"><span class="text-info">Precio:&nbsp;$<?php echo $datos[$i]['Precio'];?></span></h5>
                <span>Cantidad:&nbsp;</span>
                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Cantidad'];?>" data-precio="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Precio'];?>" data-id="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Id'];?>" class="cantidad form-control" size="2" maxlength="2" required onKeyPress="return SoloNumeros(event);" onPaste="return false">
                <center><span class="text-success subtotal">Subtotal:&nbsp;$<?php echo $datos[$i]['Cantidad']*$datos[$i]['Precio'];?></span></center>
                <center><a href="#" class="eliminar btn btn-danger" data-id="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Id']?>"><span class="icon-bin"></span>ELIMINAR</a></center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

El propio bucle **for** te está dando la solución:

```
count($datos);
```

El **for** va a hacer tantas iteraciones como productos haya, por eso se inicializa a `$i = 0` e itera hasta `$i<count($datos)` que no es otra cosa que hasta el número de productos.

Answer (score 1):

Pues creo que basta con algo que ya estás haciendo: `count($datos)` te da el total de elementos. Si lo haces directamente sobre la variable de sesión pues te evitas inicializar una variable: `count($_SESSION['carrito'])` (Siempre que la sesión tenga un carrito, claro)

Answer (score 0):

Si en el array de `$datos` solo vienen cadenas de texto, números o valores simples, puedes usar `$result = count($datos)` y te ahorras hacer el for. Si dentro del array hay otros arrays, la cosa se complica.

Comment: también podrías utilizar foreach(), si inicialmente no sabes cuantos te llegan, y no necesitas saberlo (solo iterar los) con foreach puedes recorrer dicho array. Por supuesto las soluciones anteriores también te dan el total de elementos.